# Time complexity for a specific recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

How should one go about to find the time complexity of `sum1`?

```
func sum1(x []int) int {
    // Returns the sum of all the elements in the list x.
    return sum(x, 0, len(x)-1)
}

func sum(x []int, i int, j int) int {
    // Returns the sum of the elemets from x[i] to x[j]
    if i > j {
        return 0
    }
    if i == j {
        return x[i]
    }
    mid := (i + j) / 2
    return sum(x, i, mid) + sum(x, mid+1, j)

}
```

Is it correct that the amount of steps requried for this specific algorithm is 
`T(n)= 1 + 2*T(n/2)` ?
where `n` is the amount of elements in the array?

Comment: "amount of steps" is a bit vague, but your formula is more or less correct. You better write O(1) instead of 1. Then apply the master theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The `i>j` case can never happen via `sum1` unless the user passes in an empty list, so let's ignore it for the calculation of the time complexity.

Otherwise a call to `sum(x[], i, j)` either returns an element of `x`, or adds to things together. If the result is the sum of `x[i]+x[i+1]+...+x[j]`, then it must be the case that there's `j-i+1` cases that return an element of `x`, and `j-i` cases that perform an addition. Thus there must be a total of `2j-2i+1` calls to `sum`, and so the complexity of `sum1` is O(len(x)).

Note that this code is pointless -- it's just a very complicated and overhead-heavy way of doing the same(*) as the naive code `for i = 0..n-1 {sum += x[i]} return sum`. (*) assuming addition is associative.

If you want a recursive formulation of T(n) (where n is j-i+1), then it's T(1)=1, T(n) = T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil(n/2)) + 1. You will get the right complexity if you approximate it with T(n)=2T(n/2)+1, but it isn't *quite* right unless you state that n is a power of 2. This is a common approximation for dealing with divide-and-conquer array algorithms.